# Sage doesn't find cycle_type() attribute on a permutation element

Tags: python, sage

Im trying to work on some group theory with Sage.

In particular I was trying to learn the basic commands related to symmetric groups.

My input is

```
G=SymmetricGroup(6)

sigma=G('(1,3,5)(4,6)')
```

then I use `sigma.cycle_type()` and according to the documentation, I should get as output a list with the lengths of the cycles that form sigma in decreasing order, in this case I should get something like [3,2]. Instead I get an "AttributeError" :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-94f73ca80516> in <module>()
----> 1 sigma.cycle_type()

/home/sage/sage-7.2/src/sage/structure/element.pyx in sage.structure.element.Element.__getattr__ (/home/sage/sage-7.2/src/build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:4649)()
    411             dummy_error_message.name = name
    412             raise dummy_attribute_error
--> 413         return getattr_from_other_class(self, P._abstract_element_class, name)
    414 
    415     def __dir__(self):

/home/sage/sage-7.2/src/sage/structure/misc.pyx in sage.structure.misc.getattr_from_other_class (/home/sage/sage-7.2/src/build/cythonized/sage/structure/misc.c:1870)()
    257         dummy_error_message.cls = type(self)
    258         dummy_error_message.name = name
--> 259         raise dummy_attribute_error
    260     if isinstance(attribute, methodwrapper):
    261         dummy_error_message.cls = type(self)

AttributeError: 'sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup_element.SymmetricGroupElement' object has no attribute 'cycle_type'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you just need a newer version of Sage?  In a late beta of 7.3, I get:

```
sage: sigma.cycle_type()
[3, 2, 1]
```

I should point out that the version in SageMathCloud appears to be too old for this currently, if that's your platform...

Comment: Ok, that must be, I was running both sage 7.2 and SageMathCloud. gonna check it in 7.3. Thank you and sorry for the dull question

Comment: Nothing dull about saying Sage has added functionality!

Comment: Note that [SageMathCloud updated to Sage 7.3 in early September 2016](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/sage-cloud/xiffMzP6vZw/discussion).